# Airflow auth via AD in rest API doesn't work

Tags: api, rest, ldap, airflow

I have an Airflow application running in K8s.

It's authenticate via AD, this in web view work's fine and AD credentials allows the access, but doesn't work in rest API.

My airflow.cfg there is: `airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth` and the service was rebooted, everything based in airflow's documentation.

If we run the command in airflow service  **$ airflow config get-value api auth_backends** return `airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth`.

In my test, I'm using isomnia to request mode `basic auth` with `user` and `password` of LDAP.

But, even everything has been based in the airflow documentation, all requests return
`401 - Unauthorized`

```
{
"detail": null,
"status": 401,
"title": "Unauthorized",
"type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.3/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/Unauthenticated"
}
```

I think my requests are correct,  I've did an connection in airflow without LDAP/AD and works.

I've read airflow service log and all requests contain there, but does not allow the access.

I'm not found many documentation about it and the airflow documentation of API authentication is really limited.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue, **the pipeline has updated airflow.cfg with configmap.**  Therefore, my description above, about airflow.cfg configurations is true, but in configmap was read deny_all.
I've resolved not excluded the question, because my problem in the pipeline might be usefull for someone else.